# Install mysql shellscript and set root password

Tags: mysql, shell

I need staff to make a shell script that installs mysql server with yum however need to install it sets the root password mysql automatically!
Most do not know how to do this can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

**One way** would be to specify the password afterwards (when you know the default)

```
mysqladmin -u root password <NEW_PASS>
```

You can try to make that part of your script.

**The other way** would be to use [here-strings](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html).

It will basically look something like this:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password <NEW_PASS>'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password <NEW_PASS>'
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

**Third way** would be to use a real provisioning framework like Chef or Puppet or other, where you use files to describe a certain type of node, similar to this:

```
class mysql-server {
     $password = "insert_password_here"
     package { "MySQL-client": ensure => installed }
     package { "MySQL-server": ensure => installed }
     package { "MySQL-shared": ensure => installed }

     exec { "Set MySQL server root password":
       subscribe => [ Package["MySQL-server"], Package["MySQL-client"], Package["MySQL-shared"] ],
       refreshonly => true,
       unless => "mysqladmin -uroot -p$password status",
       path => "/bin:/usr/bin",
       command => "mysqladmin -uroot password $password",
     }
}
```

Check out the full article [here](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/11/18/recipes-for-automated-installation-of-OS-and-beyond/).

**Further resources:**

[1]Configuration management [mysql with chef](http://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2013/sessions/managing-mysql-chef)

[2]Configuration management [mysql with Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/module-of-the-week-puppetlabs-mysql-mysql-management)